# How to Embed a table into QGIS Graphic Modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am automating a process in QGIS. So far, I have built the following model.

[image]

The HSG Lookup.csv is a user input right now. But I want it to be a predefined table(or csv file) embedded into the model and not the user input.

Is there a way to do that within the modeler?

Comment: If you wish to ask about Python too then please do so in a separate question and include a code attempt.

Comment: Have you tried inputting the table as a Matrix parameter?

Comment: @csk thanks. No, I was not aware of this functionality, before I try that can you tell me if you are referring to using the Input Matrix Parameter, then wouldn't it ask the user to put this parameter. What I want is it to be an embedded table and not ask user for input.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the input matrix parameter. When I tried it, it looks like you can set the number of rows and columns, and also fill in values in all the cells, when building the model. So I'm thinking it might not require the user to input this parameter. I don't have a functioning model so I wasn't able to test that myself. I'm also not sure if you can use a matrix parameter in an algorithm that accepts a CSV as input. Hence why it's just a suggestion in a comment instead of posted as an answer. :)

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and update here.

Comment: The only solution I know of would be to export your model to a python processing script and edit it to handle this behavior with either a memory layer created in code or a temporary file more likely.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by clicking on the "Select File" icon, and then searching for your CSV file. The user will not be asked about this file, you can remove it from model´s entries as well.

[image]

**EDIT:** This file is not embedded with the model, it must always be stored in the same place and with the same name to work.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and I will do that if I can't figure out any way to embed the table but what I ideally want is to send someone the model without having to ask him/her to separately place the table at a specific location.

Comment: @Someone191 I believe this will not be possible even with python. This could be possible in a compilation, but this is a programming matter that I have no knowledge.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have knowledge about this as well. Do you think it would be possible to package it, (and other files, I have a style file that I want to package as well) if I make it a plugin?

Comment: I believe it is possible. I recommend you to research and maybe create another question like "how to call fixed files in a plugin".